# print html tag by typescript in html page

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

It is an angular app.
I want to call one component inside another component.
So, if I write in 1st component like this to call 2nd component using 2nd component's selector:

**html:**

```
<div>
    <app-nice-component></app-nice-component>
</div>
```

All works fine.

But I have a lot of components, If I try to do the same from an array, it is no longer an HTML tag, it becomes an string (and my 2nd component is no longer loading)

**ts:**

```
let x: string[] = [{<app-nice-component></app-nice-component>},{<app-nice2-component></app-nice2-component>}]
```

**html:**

```
<div>
    {{x[0]}}
</div>
```

So how can I make it an HTML tag, not an string, in 2nd case?

Comment: I think what you are trying to achieve will give you alot of problems with `AOT` compilation

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read the next doc about dynamic component loader in Angular: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

You need to load dynamically the components. Steps:

1. Create a directive for telling your HTML code where to load the components:

   ```
   @Directive({
       selector: '[myDirective]'
   })
   export class MyDirective {
       constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }
   }
   ```
2. Setup your HTML with the new directive into a ng-template, don't forget to add the directive in the module that is using it.

   ```
   <div>
       Component loading:
       <ng-template myDirective></ng-template>
   </div>
   ```
3. Create a function for dynamic loading, it is necessary to import all the components that you want to use, in this example I prepare 3 components and dynamically load all of them, you can play with the componentToLoad array to load more or less components dynamically.

   ```
   ngOnInit() {

       let componentToLoad : any[];
       componentToLoad = [ this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(Component1Component), 
                           this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(Component2Component),
                           this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(Component3Component) ]

       const viewContainerRef = this.myDirective.viewContainerRef;

       componentToLoad.forEach( c => {
           viewContainerRef.createComponent(c);
       });
   }
   ```